# CodeIgniter: cookies, sessions, too many redirects?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I created a website using CodeIgniter 2.2 but I'm having some issues with the sessions and the cookies.

Everything works fine in localhost with this config (in application/config/):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/project/';
...
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

But when I upload the website on my server I either get an *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS* with **either of those** config when going to the subfolder when my CI website is (domain.com/test/):

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".domain.com";
```

After having such an error, going to domain.com/other won't work either. I have to quit the web browser to come back.

So I tried another config that I found on a thread here that I can't find anymore, and now it's the log in process (sessions) that won't work.

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = str_replace("http:/","",str_replace("https://","", $config['base_url']));
```

---

The method used to log in is the following:

**view/template/header.php**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('verifylogin/');?>">

    <input type="text" size="20" name="username" placeholder="username"/><br/>
    <input type="password" size="20" name="password" placeholder="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="current" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" /><br/>

</form>
```

**controllers/verifylogin.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('users_model','',TRUE);
    // does not seem to work $this->load->driver('session');
  }

  function index()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Log in';

    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    $this->form_validation->run();
    redirect($this->input->post('current'), 'refresh');

    return $data;
  }

  function check_database($password)
  {
    //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //query the database
    $result = $this->users_model->login($username, $password);

    if($result)
    {
      $sess_array = array();
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $sess_array = array(
          'id' => $row->id,
          'username' => $row->name
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

        $set = $this->users_model->get_settings($row->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('settings', $set);
      }
      return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's because in your controller you havent dont the form_validation as you're supposed to.

Comment: Instead of  redirect($this->input->post('current'), 'refresh') simply try to load your view and pass the $data variable also check whether form is actually being submitted or not by if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') See if this helps you :)

Comment: @killstreet What do you mean?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I will try to load the view directly! I've checked differently that the form is submitted (by redirecting to one page if the login is correct and another if it's not), and it worked. So my guess is that the form is correctly submitted and the code working **but** the session data does not "stick", somehow. Hence why I think that this is linked to the cookies...

Comment: @mtefi then you can check 
function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('users_model','',TRUE);  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!==false){ //redirect somewhere else  }

Comment: @PraveenKumar sadly none of this worked; I found a hack to fix this: I use native PHP sessions... but it's just a workaround, I now have to refactor my whole code.

Comment: are you actually leaving the $config['base_url'] with localhost when you upload?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browsing history,cookies etc.

Comment: Clear all sesssions from \application\cache\session